# g++ incorrect loop?

Tags: c++, g++, disassembly

I have a real world program that is similar to this one, which I'll call `test.cpp`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

extern void f(size_t i);

int sample(size_t x)
{
     size_t a = x;
     size_t i;  

     for (i = a-2; i>=0; i--) {
           f(i);   
     }
}
```

And my problem is that i is an infinite loop.

If I run the following command:

```
g++ -S -o test.s test.cpp
```

I get the following assembly sequence:

```
        .file   "test.cpp"
        .text
        .globl  _Z6samplem
        .type   _Z6samplem, @function
_Z6samplem:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        subq    $32, %rsp
        movq    %rdi, -24(%rbp)
        movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
        movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
        subq    $2, %rax
        movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
.L2:
        movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        call    _Z1fm
        subq    $1, -16(%rbp)
        jmp     .L2
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   _Z6samplem, .-_Z6samplem
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I'm no expert in assembly language, but I would expect to see code for the comparison `i >= 0` and a conditional jump out of the loop. What's going on here??

GNU C++ 4.6.3 on Ubuntu Linux

Comment: Could you clarify "gets to be negative"? Note that a "size_t" can never be negative, so you will run into an inifite loop as i>=0 is always true.

Comment: indeed, it's an infinite loop because i wraps to all ones and then on to 0 and so on... the question whas why is there no test in assembly, and the answer is it's being optimised out even though no optimisation has been requested from the compiler.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`size_t` is unsigned, so the condition `i>=0` is always `true`.  It is impossible for `i` to be negative.

Comment: Fantastic! so the comparison is being optimised away! Thanks.

Comment: Does that imply that the above loop is an infinite loop because of wrap-around of the integer type?

Comment: @JonasWielicki:  Yes.  Unless `f` throws or otherwise causes control not to return to `sample`, the loop will iterate until the thread is terminated.

Comment: The practical alternative is `i != std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()` which will break the loop on underflow. Or go signed for `i` if possible.

Comment: +1 Yes!  The compiler suppressed the fact sample never exited!  When I changed i to int, the compiler then complained that sample didn't return an int.  Great catch!